# How to return anonymous objects as the result of LINQ-to-SQL queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a tool that allows users to run SQL SELECT commands and the results will be displayed in an HTML table. I am using ASP.NET Core MVC and trying to avoid using `SqlConnection`/`SqlCommand`/etc. if possible, going straight through `DataContext`.

For example, if someone types in

`"SELECT Id, Name FROM Table"`

and the results are

```
Id | Name
------------
1  | 'Bob'
2  | 'Harry'
```

I want `Json(results)` to be

```
[
   { Id: 1, Name: "Bob" },
   { Id: 2, Name: "Harry"}
]
```

where I suppose that results would be of type `IEnumerable<object>`.

What I have now is a method in my repository like

```
    public List<object> RunQuery(string query)
    {
        using(MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            return context.MiscTable.FromSql<object>(query).ToList();
        }
    }
```

but then I get an exception like

> $exception    {System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'SomeColumn' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

where `SomeColumn` is some column on `MiscTable`. So apparently I can only query specific tables using `FromSql`. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: context.Database.SqlQuery<T> may do what you need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Doesn't seem to exist on the Database in .NET Core :(

Comment: how do you plan to access object members if you lack a class definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `.FromSql`with ad-hoc models. The fields returned from the query **must exactly** match the model (no missing fields).

Ad-hoc/non-entity models are not supported yet in EF Core but are on the roadmap.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap

> **Raw SQL queries for non-Model types** allows a raw SQL query to be used to populate types that are not part of the model (typically for denormalized view-model data).

Also anonymous classes can't be returned, since their type is only know at compile type. You should create models for your entities in the database (usually 1 model per table, but you can also have more models in one table via inheritance). That's what ORM is for.

If you just want raw queries, use ADO.NET directly. ORMs are there for mapping tables to classes/objects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `.Include()` to add additional tables to the dbset your FromSql operates on.  Check out this link for examples and additional context.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#composing-with-linq

From your example, your query might look like this:

```
return context.MiscTable.Include(t => t.RelatedTable).FromSql<object>(query).ToList();
```

Disclaimer:  I didn't actually try this, so I'm not sure it will actually work.  But it seems reasonable.